# Some diracology in traces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, trace

Suppose I want to evaluate the trace $p_{\alpha} q_{\beta}\text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} \gamma^0)$.  Using the standard trace formula for four gamma matrices I arrive at $$p_{\alpha} q_{\beta}\text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} \gamma^0) = 4p_{\alpha} q_{\beta}(2g^{0 \alpha} g^{0 \beta} - g^{\alpha \beta})$$ Contracting the indices gives me $4(p^0 q^0 + \mathbf p \cdot \mathbf q)$ which is the answer I know to be correct.

But lets proceed in another way: Write $$p_{\alpha} q_{\beta}\text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} \gamma^0) = p_{\alpha} q_{\beta} (\text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 (-\gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} + 2g^{0 \beta}))) = p_{\alpha}q_{\beta} (-\text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^{\beta}) + 2 \text{Tr}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^{\beta})) )$$ using the clifford algebra and the fact $\gamma_0^2 = 1$. Then we have $$\text{Tr} (\not p \not q) = 4 p \cdot q = 4(p^0 q^0 - \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf q)$$ So I have a minus error in the second term. Did I miss a term somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You go from
$$
\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 (-\gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} + 2g^{0 \beta})\big]
$$
to
$$
-\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^{\beta}\big] + 2 \text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^{\beta}\big]
$$
but this is wrong. The correct result is

$$
\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 (-\gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} + 2g^{0 \beta})\big]=-\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\big] +2g^{0 \beta}\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0\big]
$$

Finally, take $\text{Tr}[\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}]=4g^{\alpha\beta}$ and $\text{Tr}[\gamma^\alpha\gamma^0]=4g^{\alpha 0}$:

$$
\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^0 (-\gamma^0 \gamma^{\beta} + 2g^{0 \beta})\big]=-4g^{\alpha\beta}+8g^{0 \beta}g^{\alpha0}
$$
which is the same result you got first.

Comment: Okay, thanks! The only question I would have is, why is $\gamma_0 g^{0 \beta} = \gamma^{\beta}$ not valid?

Comment: Because in $\gamma_0 g^{0\beta}$ there is not a sum: the index $0$ is **not contracted**, but is fixed to the single value "$0$". Take for example $\beta=1$. Then the l.h.s. you have $\gamma_0 g^{01}=0$ (because $g^{01}=0$) while on the r.h.s you have $\gamma^1\neq 0$. You can see that l.h.s$\neq$r.h.s. (if I didn't make myself clear please say so and I'll try to explain better).

Comment: Yes it's clear! thanks, I just realised as well - $$\gamma_{\alpha}  g^{\alpha \beta} = \gamma^{\beta}  = \gamma_0 g^{0 \beta} + \gamma_i g^{i \beta}$$ so what I wrote is indeed not true. I guess something perhaps more conceptually though: The $\gamma_{\mu}$ are matrices so why do they obey the same raising/lowering property with the metric  as four vectors do?

Comment: nice! the matrices $\gamma_\mu$ (with lower indices) are **defined** to be $\gamma_\mu\equiv g_{\mu\nu}\gamma^\nu$. This means: they obey the same raising/lowering properties because we **define** them to. The matrices with **upper indices** are given by the Clifford algebra. The matrices with **lower indices** are defined by contracting with the metric. Its just notation.